# HTTP request via AJAX or form-submit. Which one should I choose and why?

Tags: php, ajax, post, get, form-submit

I have a PHP page with a simple form. One input text field & a button. Input text field accepts user queries & on button click an HTTP GET request is made to the server & the result has to be shown back in the same page containing the form. That's too simple to do. I can do this in two ways. One is AJAX & other one is the good old sodding form-submit method.

My question is simple- Which method should I use? Since both of the roads lead us to the same place, which one should I choose to travel?

First of all, let me talk about form submit method. I can use `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ; ?>` as the action of  the form for submitting the values of my form to the same page. Once I store those values into some random variables, I can make a GET request & obtain the result & show it to the world. This method is easy to use. Happy Down Voting to all of you.

Or I can make a GET request using AJAX and jQuery or JavaScript or whatever you wish to use & obtain the same result as in the previous case. Output is same. Only the mode of execution is different.

So which one is better? Which one fetches result faster? And why should I use that? Is there any difference? GET, POST, PUT or whatever- it doesn't really matter. AJAX or form-submit?

Comment: To my mind, one of the reasons to use Ajax is to improve users experiences (eg: a deletion). Under no circumstances it will make your app faster. Unless, for instance, if you are using Ajax to load products 10/10. Instead of loading 10000 products at the beginning. Moreover, keep in mind that users can disable javascript.

Comment: Point noted. :) Thanks. @Debflav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any significant, genuine speed difference between them.

The Ajax approach will load a smaller amount of data (since you aren't loading an entire HTML document), but by the time you take into account HTTP compression and the fact that (if your system is sensibly configured) your dependancies (images, scripts, stylesheets, etc) will be cached, it won't be significantly smaller.

By using JavaScript to create a loading indicator and not refreshing the entire window in front of the user, you can create the illusion of a faster load time though. So if feeling faster was the only concern, then Ajax is the way forward.

Using JavaScript, however, is more complicated and slightly more prone to failure. The consequences of failure states are more severe because, unless your code detects and does something with them, the user will (not) see it fail silently. For example, if a normal page load times out because the user is on a train and went through a tunnel, they'll see an error page provided by their browser suggesting that they refresh and try again. With Ajax, you need to write the error handling code yourself. This does give you more flexibility (such as allowing you to simply try again a few times) but the work isn't done for you.

The other consequence of using Ajax is that the address bar will not update automatically. This means that the results won't be bookmarkable or sharable unless you do something explicit the make that possible. The usual way to do that is [`pushState` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries), but again, it is more work.

You should also [make the site work without JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) so that if the JS doesn't run for any reason then the site won't break completely. If you use `pushState` then you have to do this for the URLs you are setting the address bar to point to to be useful.

The short answer: Use a regular form submission, then consider layering JavaScript over the top if you think it will give your visitors a worthwhile benefit.

Answer (score -1):

I Should stick to an `Ajax` request when possible.

This because you then don't really have to load every single item on the page again ( like all the images, menu and so on ). You can just give the relevant HTML back and JQuery can place it inside the relevant holder.

But that is just my humble opinion...

Comment: Your opinion has been considered. Let me see more answers.

Answer (score -1):

See the **edited** one it may help you.

I think that AJAX should be used for displays updates and form submissions should be done via a page reload. Reasoning?

When submitting forms, you are telling the application to do something. Users tend to want to feel that it was done. When a page doesn't reload, users are often left wondering "Did that work?". Then they have to check to make sure what they did was right.

but when you are displaying a table or something, and the user says to "display x data....now x1 data" for instance, they aren't "doing" something (creating new entities, sending emails, etc). So AJAX can provide a nice user interface in this case. Page reloads would be annoying here.

In conclusion, I think form submission should be done via page reloads (let the user see it working), whereas display updates should use AJAX (prevent annoying page reloads).

Of course, this is a preference thing. Some of my company's applications use AJAX all over. But those are the applications that are the most difficult to maintain and debug. ;)``

Comment: This is plain information that I can get from google. I was looking for opinions.

Answer (score -1):

If you have to retrive simple data from server without reload the page my advice is use jquery .get o .post

also it provides you a very large API that allows you to reduce your programming time.
http://api.jquery.com/

obviously the execution time increase but in my experience the user cant fell the differce with a simple ajax request.

so in my opinion if jquery allow you to obtain the results, this is the best solution because halves your work time!

Comment: The question is "Should I use Ajax or just submit a form?" not "Given that I have decided to use Ajax, should I use a library to help and if so, which ?"

Comment: Well said quentin. @Quentin